# Add an entry in right-click context menu and thereby running a java program

Tags: java, windows, right-click, regedit

I am trying to invoke a java program by right clicking a file, which will use that file for some operation. The working should be such that, if i right click on a file, there should be present a menu item, such as "ClickMe". On clicking this, a java program should be invoked by passing the complete path of the file being clicked.

I tried something using REGEDIT. But, it doesn't work. What i used is :

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ * \shell\ClickMe\Command default="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_39\bin\java Test". (Test is the class name.)

But then, on clicking the ClickMe, an OpenWith window appeared.

I am stuck here. I would wonder if anyone just pull me out of this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you include the classpath? My guess is part of the problem is that java has no idea where Test is.

Comment: Test file is in the bin itself.

Answer (score 0):

Same here. I borrowed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28703971/1832104), and used CMD to launch it instead:

```
cmd /c javaw -jar c:\tools\convert.jar --outfile converted.csv
```