# executing .jar file with an argument by mouse right-click on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, jar, right-click

I find the ChkBugReport to be very interesting:
http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/tools/analyse-your-bugreports-with-our-open-source-tool/

so I would like to use it on my Windows7 but in a simple way.

In order to use the tool that is in jar, I need to type the following in the command prompt:

**java -jar ChkBugReport_ver.jar dumplog.txt**

where the dumplog.txt is the log I want to analyze by the tool.

The thing is that it is quite tiresome to run cmd and then type "java -jar... blah blah.." everytime I want to use it so I would like to link it to the mouse right-click context menu in Windows Explorer.

i.e., browse through to the file I want to analyze in Windows Explorer, then right-clicking on it would provide a menu like "run ChkBugReport.." then it does the "java -jar ChkBugReport_ver.jar clicked-file.txt" and generates the output.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Open regedit (as administrator).
2. Locate key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell`. In case you want to add the context menu for a specific extension only, use e.g. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.xml\shell` for `xml`. If the `shell` key doesn't exist, create it (right-click on the parent key and select `New -> Key`).
3. Right-click on the `shell` key, and select `New -> Key`. Enter the name of the command displayed in the context menu, e.g. `Check Bug Report`.
4. Right-click on the `Check Bug Report` key and select `New -> Key`. Enter text `command` (in lowercase).
5. Click on the `command` key and then double-click on the (Default) key in the right pane to edit the string value. Enter the command to be executed. Placeholder for the argument is `%1`. For `ChkBugReport_ver.jar`, you can use

   ```
   java -jar "C:\Path\To\ChkBugReport_ver.jar" "%1"
   ```

See also [this tutorial](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-any-application-to-the-desktop-right-click-menu-in-vista/).

*(Works with my Windows 7)*

Comment: I already checked this out but I would like to run it with one extra argument - the selected file so it would execute "java -jar ChkBugReport_ver.jar selected_file"

Comment: see my updated answer - the placeholder for the argument should be %1

Comment: it doesn't work - the menu appears only when a folder is selected in the left tree of the Windows Explorer.. not with a file

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly - except that the %1 also should be wrapped by the quotation marks: java -  jar "C:\Path\To\ChkBugReport_ver.jar" "%1"

Comment: Works for me with .bat files, but with jars it just yields a popup with the folder path I clicked on and "Application not found".

Comment: `java -jar "D:\Path\To\MyJar.jar"`. It works just fine if I enter it into the console though. I guess I should mention that I'm on Windows 8.1, but that shouldn't matter since the problem is running `java -jar` specifically.

Comment: Hm, are the system variables such as PATH, JAVA_HOME and such set up correctly?

Comment: Well, everything else works just fine so I guess so. JAVA_HOME is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_40`, and Path starts with `%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;`.

Comment: Then it may be worth starting a new question with your specific conditions.

Comment: I tried this, but Windows 10 keeps popping up "How do you want to open this?". Any solutions?

Comment: How do we add a custom icon? And what about selecting multiple files?

Answer (score 5):

The best answer above didn't work for me, it just opened a new window asking me what I'd like to open it with. I found a command that works much better. Same as first answer above but slightly different command (#4): `cmd /k java` instead of `java`. It runs it in a cmd window and the file is created in the current directory of the bug report.

1. Locate key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell`
   (Create shell key if it doesn't exist)
2. Right-click on the shell key, select `New -> Key`. Enter the name of the command you'd like to display in the context menu (ie. Check Bug Report).
3. Right-click on the "Check  Bug Report" key you just created and select New -> Key. Name it `command`.
4. Click on the command key, double-click on the (Default) key in the right pane and enter the following command to be executed:
   `cmd /k java -jar  c:\PATH\Chkbugreport.jar "%1"`

Comment: This worked with my Windows 10... Thanks! Side note: it does keep the cmd window opened.

Comment: `cmd /C java -jar c:\Path\myjar.jar "%1"`

Comment: @SimonBaars : /C is the "close" switch, /K is the "stay open" switch

Answer (score 0):

try add it to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell

I use the following registry to add Notepad2 to the right-click content menu

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Notepad2]
@="Notepad2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Notepad2\command]
@="D:\Tools\Notepad2\Notepad2.exe %1"